# Django - Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

An error occurs when I try to save the data.

Column 'user_id' cannot be null.

Below are the settings I'm using for the Model

```
class XML(models.Model):
    nome_destinatario = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cnpj_destinatario = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_destinatario
```

Serializer

```
class XMLCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = XML
        fields = ('nome_destinatario', 'cnpj_destinatario', 'user_id')
```

View

```
xml_create = XMLCreateSerializer(data={'nome_emitente': 'NILVA', 'cnpj_destinatario':'5645654654','user_id': 1})

        if xml_create.is_valid():
            salvo = xml_create.save()
        else:
            salvo = xml_create.errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field in `XML` model is `user`, therefore in `serializer` use:

```
fields = ('nome_destinatario', 'cnpj_destinatario', 'user')
```

Also, in `view`, pass `data` as:

```
data={'nome_emitente': 'NILVA', 'cnpj_destinatario':'5645654654','user': 1}
```

It will work. Always use same name in `serializer` fields as they are in you `model`.